# How do I make the wordpress menu active(highlight) when the woocommerce category is selected?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Help me find a solution. How to apply an active menu to woocommerce (product_cat) categories so that a specific menu is highlighted for certain categories.

There is a menu of two items. Apples and Pears, each product has its own category, apples (category1, category2, category3) pears (category 4, category 5) How to make active(add current-menu-item) the menu that a certain category belongs to. If the categories are selected (category1, category2, category3), the menu is Apples, and pears, respectively, are not. If a category is selected (category 4, category 5) then the active menu is Pears.

Here is the Apple menu id menu 118 and there is a woocommerce product category (Category 1 (cat 1)) it has an id 86.
If I selected the woocommerce product category (cart 1) then the Apples menu should be highlighted as active or for example the Home menu.

This code makes all menu items active if a category is selected (cat 1).
I need to be able to choose which menu item will be active if I select a product category (cat 1). I want only the Apple menu item (id 118) to be active)

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_custom_class', 10, 2 );

function add_custom_class( $classes, $item )  {
    if ( is_product_category( 'cat1' ) ) {
         $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Hi you need to have a go at this, post some code and tell us where the problem is. Then people can help. I'm guessing though that this problem might have already been solved in woo comerence

Comment: Hi! Updated! See

Comment: and the problem is.....
TBO: I don't know woocommerce but as much information as you can provide would assist whoever does.

Comment: So is there any errors? Maybe a few echos to try and debug your code.
Is that is_product_category correct?